# Does Prime number always has the same pattern after 7 every +30

Tags: javascript, primes

i see the code below from http://www.javascripter.net/faq/numberisprime.htm

```
leastFactor = function(n){
 if (isNaN(n) || !isFinite(n)) return NaN;  
 if (n==0) return 0;  
 if (n%1 || n*n<2) return 1;
 if (n%2==0) return 2;  
 if (n%3==0) return 3;  
 if (n%5==0) return 5;  
 var m = Math.sqrt(n);
 for (var i=7;i<=m;i+=30) {
  if (n%i==0)      return i;
  if (n%(i+4)==0)  return i+4;
  if (n%(i+6)==0)  return i+6;
  if (n%(i+10)==0) return i+10;
  if (n%(i+12)==0) return i+12;
  if (n%(i+16)==0) return i+16;
  if (n%(i+22)==0) return i+22;
  if (n%(i+24)==0) return i+24;
 }
 return n;
}
```

Does this mean that prime number always has same pattern every 30 after number 7?

Does this mean that from 7, when you add 30 
the result of that number is prime, that number +4 is prime, that number +6 is always prime, and so on until +24, and there would be no more prime number between them?

Comment: This is just an implementation of wheel factorization. But I don't understand the line that returns 1. Certainly n%1 is always 0, no matter the value of n, and n*n<2 is true only when n is -1, 0 or 1. And in any event 1 is a factor of every number, so it's not useful to ever return 1. Likewise, on the line before that, it's not useful to return 0. It's better to throw an error when n is less than 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, but this code works because it is simply checking all values (sort of). You know that if a number is even, it is a multiple of 2 and not prime. Likewise, if it the rightmost digit is 5, you know that it is divisible by 5 and not prime. Using many rules like this, we can eliminate checking many different values that meet one of these parameters.

So, the script checks 2, sees that 2 is not a multiple of the input and knows that it never needs to check an even number again, so on and so forth.

The for loop is not generating only prime numbers. It could generate 187, which is not prime, but in practice, it never will because once the function checks 11, it will return.

Answer (score 2):

It is basically just avoiding rechecks of divisors that aren't possible because they are multiples of 2,3 or 5, which have already been checked.  And this is a repeating pattern of still-possible divisors just because the product of 2,3 and 5 is 30.

Primes have not been found to follow a very predictable pattern at all.

Answer (score 1):

What that code is doing is highly optimized - it's essentially doing the same as 'does 3 divide into n evenly? does 4 divide into n evenly? does 5 divide into n evenly?' but it uses important pieces of knowledge such as 'after 2, no even number is prime' to skip checking all even factors (notice that it will do 7 + even numbers, 37 + even numbers, 67 plus even numbers and so on - so never an even number). Similarly, it skips every sixth factor since it would be a multiple of 3.